# How can I change uniform to normal?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I'm taking one statistic course, and I'm confused...

the question is

A candymaker produces mints that have a label weight of 10 grams. Assume that the distribution of the weight of such a mint is uniform over (9.5, 10.5).

(a) Let X be the weight of a single mint selected at random from the production line. Find P(9.9 < X < 10.1)

So what I can't understand is, "unifrom over (9.5, 10.5)"

Here, is my solution, but I'm not sure it is right or wrong..

I think, E of uniform is (a+b)/2 and V of unifrom is (b-a)^2/12

so, I assume that if I change it to normal distribution, I would get N(10, 1/12).

Then, P( (9.9 - 10)/root(1/12) < Z < (10.1 - 10)/root(1/12))

=> P(-0.35 < Z <0.35). So, P(Z<0.35) = 0.6368, then P(-0.35 < Z < 0.35) is 0.2736.

However, professor gave answer sheet, and it said it is "0.2"(there's no solution, just answer)

What part am I wrong at? or it is just professor think 0.6368 ~ 0.6?

If professor says P(Z<0.35) ~ 0.6, then 0.2 might be correct.

But I'm not sure what is right.

If my solution is wrong, can you tell me what is wrong and explain it?(like, uniform to normal is wrong)

Comment: You are hugely overthinking this problem - 'uniform to normal' is both wrong and completely unnecessary here. What is your definition of a uniform deviate? This question should be easily answerable from the definition itself.

Comment: yeah I read textbook carefully again with those two answers, so now I know what is wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Uniform distribution is something entirely different than normal distribution, so you should not try to switch to normal distribution (whatever that means).

[Uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) means that the probability is constant over the interval. In particular, if something is uniform over an interval $[a,b]$ it means that the probability density function is
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1/(b-a) &\mbox{if } a\leq x\leq b \\ 
0 & \mbox{otherwise }
\end{cases} $$
Then you have that
$$P(x_1 < X < x_2) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)\, \mathrm d x.$$

Comment: Thanks. It is just because of my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert to a normal distribution unless you are looking at the sum or the average of many uniformly distributed random variables.

Uniform $p(x) = \begin{cases}\frac {1}{b-a}&x\in (a,b)\\0&x\notin(a,b)\end{cases}$

When $x$ is uniformly distributed as described above.

$P(x\in (9.9, 10.1)) = \frac {10.1-9.9}{10.5-9.5} = 0.2$

Comment: OMG I am totally misunderstand it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? Question (b) is that X_bar is the sample mean of the 100 selected mints, i.e. X_bar = (X1 + X2 + ... + X100)/100. Find P(9.9<X_bar<10.1). The answer is 1, and the mean of uniform is (a+b)/2 = 10. Because 10 is always between 9.9 and 10,1, so that's why P(9.9<X_bar<10.1) is 1?

Comment: Now that you are averaging 100 samples together, you can use that normal distribution.  As $n$ gets large $\bar X$ starts to resemble a normal distribution.  $\mu = 10,  \sigma^2 = \frac {1}{12(n)}$